# Nesting a given array into children, based on condition

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have an array like this:

```
tweets = [
  {
    :user_id => 234567,
    :username => "A",
    :created_at => "2012-10-12 10:20:30"
  },
  {
    :user_id => 234568,
    :username => "B",
    :created_at => "2012-10-12 10:20:34"
  },
  {
    :user_id => 234569,
    :username => "C",
    :created_at => "2012-10-12 10:20:35"
  },
  {
    :user_id => 234570,
    :username => "D",
    :created_at => "2012-10-12 10:20:40"
  }
]
```

and another array, like this:

```
followers = [
  {
    :user_id => 234567,
    :follower_ids => [234568, 56654]
  },
  {
    :user_id => 234568,
    :follower_ids => [234569, 454445]
  },
  {
    :user_id => 234569,
    :follower_ids => [234570, 56333]
  },
  {
    :user_id => 234570,
    :follower_ids => [45566, 61145]
  }
]
```

I want to nest it into a deep structure, where one is made into children of another. For making the children, the condition to be satisfied is:

> any other tweet which has a greater `created_at` than the other, and
>   whose `user_id` is included in the follower_ids list if that tweet in
>   the followers array is considered to be a child

and the expected output for the given data is like this:

```
arranged_tweets = [
  {
    :user_id => 234567,
    :username => "A",
    :created_at => "2012-10-12 10:20:30",
    :children => [
      {
        :user_id => 234568,
        :username => "B",
        :created_at => "2012-10-12 10:20:34",
        :children => [
          {
            :user_id => 234569,
            :username => "C",
            :created_at => "2012-10-12 10:20:35",
            :children => [
              {
                :user_id => 234570,
                :username => "D",
                :created_at => "2012-10-12 10:20:40"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: How did you do this without writing any code?

Comment: @theTinMan..do you mean to say, what code I have tried?

Answer (score 1):

Untested, but should give you the idea:

```
arranged_tweets = tweets.collect do |tweet|
  arranged_tweet(tweet, tweets - [tweet])          
end

def arranged_tweet(tweet, other_tweets)
  { :user_id => tweet[:user_id], ...
    :children => children(tweet, other_tweets) }
end 

def children(tweet, other_tweets)
  other_tweets.find_all { |other| is_child?(other, tweet) }.collect do |other|
    arranged_tweet(other, other_tweets - [other]) 
  end              
end

def is_child?(tweet, parent_tweet)
   parent_tweet[:created_at] > tweet[:created_at] && 
     is_follower?(tweet[:user_id], parent_tweet[:user_id])                                  
end

def is_follower?(user_id, other_user_id)
  followers[other_user_id][:follower_ids].include?(user_id)
end
```

Comment: I tried it..but was not able to get it correct..eventually I worked on it myself and came up with a loopy and maybe inefficient answer.